# Two sockets won't connect to one another (C++)

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock

I am working with C++ networking, and have almost written my first program, consisting of a server and a client that connect to one another. Here is my code-

server.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{



    int wsasuccessful;
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD DLLVERSION;
    DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    wsasuccessful = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &WinSockData);
    if (wsasuccessful != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d while starting WSA\n", wsasuccessful);
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;
    int AddressSize = sizeof(ADDRESS);
    SOCKET uc_socket;



    uc_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(444);
    if (WSAGetLastError() != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d while establishing socket\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    bind(uc_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&ADDRESS, AddressSize);
    if (WSAGetLastError() != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d while binding socket\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    listen(uc_socket, 12);
    if (WSAGetLastError() != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d while binding socket\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }


    SOCKET c_socket;
    SOCKADDR client_sock;
    int client_sock_size = sizeof(client_sock);
    printf("Socket created; Set to listen for incoming connections");
    c_socket = accept(uc_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&client_sock, &client_sock_size);
    printf("Connection found!");



    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

client.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int wsasuccessful = -1;
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD DLLVERSION;
    DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    wsasuccessful = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &WinSockData);
    if (wsasuccessful != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d in client while starting WSA\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    SOCKET client_socket;
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (WSAGetLastError() != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d in client while instantiating socket\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 1;
    }



    SOCKADDR_IN client_connection;
    client_connection.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client_connection.sin_port = (USHORT)(444);

    client_connection.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = (unsigned long)("0.0.0.0");



    int connection_success = -1;
    printf("Connection started!");
    connection_success = connect(client_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&client_connection, sizeof(client_connection));
    if (connection_success != 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d in client while instantiating socket\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        return 2;
    }
    printf("The client has found a server!");
    printf("The last WSA error was: %d", WSAGetLastError());


    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

- I don't see any errors after going over this multiple times, but I don't get a connection after launching both (server first, of course)
- I have setup my firewall to allow the connection to the network
- The two binaries get stuck listening (of course), and connecting. Server and client, respectively.
- I checked the ports being used and the associated PIDs (netstat -a -o), and sure enough, the server was listening to port 444, as stated in the code.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: `client_connection.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = (unsigned long)("0.0.0.0");` Casting a string to an `unsigned long` makes no sense.

Comment: David is right.  You have to use `inet_addr("0.0.0.0")` or equivalent instead.

Comment: You should only check `WSAGetLastError()` if the preceding Winsock call returned -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0.0.0.0` (aka `INADDR_ANY`) is not a valid IP address for a client to `connect()` to.  If the server and client are running on the same machine, you can use `127.0.0.1` (aka `INADDR_LOOPBACK`) instead since your server is binding to `INADDR_ANY`, which includes `127.0.0.1`.

Also, these statements are wrong on the client side:

```
client_connection.sin_port = (USHORT)(444);
client_connection.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = (unsigned long)("0.0.0.0");
```

You need to use `inet_addr()` (or equivalent) to convert an IP address from string format to binary format.  And you need to use `htons()` instead, like you do on the server side:

```
client_connection.sin_port = htons(444);
client_connection.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

Also, your error handling in general is wrong.  Do not call `WSAGetLastError()` unless an error is actually reported first.  That means checking the return value of `socket()` and `accept()` for `INVALID_SOCKET`, the return value of `bind()`, `listen()`, and `connect()` for `SOCKET_ERROR` (which is -1, not 0), etc.  `connect()` is likely failing and you are not detecting the error correctly, so you think it succeeds when it really fails.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I naturally found a ton more things wrong when fixing the error reporting, but it's better that I know about them.